# Mongo Java Driver 3 - Using an object extending 'Document'

Tags: java, mongodb

Mongo Java Driver 3 added support for the [Codec infrastructure](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/bson/codecs/), which I'm trying below.  By default it comes with codecs for the following 3 objects: Document, BasicDBObject and BsonDocument.

I'm trying to do something quite simple by having my class, MyClass, extend Document.  However it fails with the error as indicated inline.

I found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/cada9eaac3e24ef5a62a) but it seems overly complex.. is there not a simple way to register MyClass as a Codec since it's also a Document?

Thank you.
-henning

```
public class PlayMongo {
    static class MyClass extends Document {
        public MyClass(String key, Object value) {
            super(key, value);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");

        // Works like a charm
        MongoCollection<Document> documentCollection = db.getCollection("docs");
        documentCollection.insertOne(new Document().append("hello", "world"));

        // Fails with CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class play.reactivemongo.PlayMongo$MyClass
        MongoCollection<MyClass> myClassCollection = db.getCollection("myclasses", MyClass.class);
        myClassCollection.insertOne(new MyClass("hello", "world"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to make it is using [Morphia](https://mongodb.github.io/morphia/). Morphia is prepared to map Java Objects to MongoDB collections. I did an example sou, you can see how it works. In this example MongoDB has a collection called `people` which maps to a Java Class called `Person`. The `Person` looks like this:

```
@Entity("people")
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    //obrigactory constructor for Morphia
    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

}
```

Morphia know that a Person object corresponds to the people collection because of the `Entity` annotation. It also demands a constructor with no parameters to properly convert the objects, so that's why we have one there.

The MongoDB Java Driver is pretty simple already, but Morphia makes it even simpler to do CRUD operations. The next chunk of code will insert and retrieve a person on the database:

```
        Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
        Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(new MongoClient(), "test");

        Person johnDoe = new Person("John", "Doe");

        //saves John Doe on DB
        datastore.save(johnDoe);

        //retrieves all people whose first name is John
        List<Person> people = datastore.createQuery(Person.class).filter("firstName", "John").asList();

        System.out.println(people.size()); //prints 1
        Person person = people.get(0);

        System.out.println(person); //prints John Doe
```

As you can see we just need to say which Java Class will be used and Morphia can then discover the right collection based on the annotations that it finds. After that a simple `save` it's enough to insert the object on the database. To retrieve the data is basically the same process: inform the class you want, along with your filter.

It's important to keep in mind that Morphia brings an extra-cost on performance. In most of the cases it won't make a difference, but you need to evaluate your scenario and run some tests of your own.

Comment: This will do.. and I like it because it's clean.  Thanks Daniel!

Answer (score 1):

I've created small library for creating codecs automatically for POJOs. If you don't want use big library like Morphia, check it at:

https://github.com/dozd/mongo-mapper

It works for synchronous as well as for asynchronous version of new mongo driver.